# Java four bytes to binary 'bitmask'

Tags: java, binary, masking

I'm trying to take four bytes from a binary file and turn them into a bit mask that represents a zero for data and a 1 for metadata.

I'm assuming I need to convert them into an int by or'ing them together and then bit shift through that to determine if a bit position is set or not.

I can't work out how to combine all four together to get a 32-bit mask that I can step though.

```
int mask = (((int)hbyte) & 0xff) << 8 | (((int)lbyte) & 0xff);
```

That would combine two together (post by Laurence Gonsalves from another post) but I can't figure out the syntax to get four together.

Or would this be case for an Enumset, which I'll admit I don't fully understand.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Tony

**Just to add another quick note to this, (I'm not sure if that's generally allowed so I apologise in advance if it's not), what is the best way of going through my newly created int and checking if a bit is set or not?

Currently I'm using`if (((comboOfBytes >> bitmaskBit) & 1) == 0)` but I don't know if that's the most elegant way of doing the check that I need.

Also I'm still not entirely sure if I understand how shifting actually allows all 32 bits to be checked!

Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `DataInputStream` to read 4 bytes as an int from your file.

Alternately, if you read bytes a, b, c, d:

```
int comboOfBytes = ((a & 0xff) << 24) | ((b & 0xff) << 16) | ((c & 0xff) << 8) | (d & 0xff);
```

The (& 0xff) is necessary to prevent sign bit extension from clobbering higher bytes.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike.  That did just the job!!

Answer (score 1):

I always use the following

```
public static int compose(byte x3, byte x2, byte x1, byte x0) {
    return (x3 << 24)
            + ((x2 & 0xFF) << 16)
            + ((x1 & 0xFF) << 8)
            + ((x0  & 0xFF) << 0);
}
```

However, you may want to use a DataStream instead.

And no, EnumSet is not the way to go. EnumSet is just an efficient implementation of Set specialized for Enums. It has no IO capabilities beyond serialization.

Comment: I believe that this is superior to the Mike Samuel solution because it allows you to generate a bitmask from less than 4 bytes.  I suggest final parameters to help catch maintenance errors.

Comment: OT: I never use final parameters, since it makes the parameter list very long and hard to read. However, I could live with all parameters being final by default.

Answer (score 0):

An EnumSet is a Set of Enum elements. You probably mean [`BitSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/BitSet.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the bigger context of what you're up to, but if you control the data structure, if you need 32 flags, I suspect it would be a whole lot easier to just create a boolean[32] array.

Yes, bit flags save memory, but unless you have millions of them, this is probably unimportant.

I'm not saying that there's never a time when an int composed of a bunch of bit flags and then being used to mask a data stream is not a good idea, but I think it is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Jay you're right, it's not a good idea and it's leading to me having massive headaches! :)  It's part of a Microsoft compression algorithm and it uses a 4 byte bitmask to denote the locations of data and metadata within a stream.  I think the reason I'm having problems is because of the way Java is reading the bytes in.